# NSCollectionView's setContent: memory management

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, memory-management, nscollectionview

I have a `NSCollectionView` that I populate using `[collectionView setContent:data];` where `data` is a `NSArray` filled with objects all of the same custom `NSObject` subclass. The item prototype of the collection view is a standard `NSCollectionViewItem`, not subclassed. The collection item's view is populated using bindings from my `NSObject` subclass.

Now to the problem, when analyzing my app using heapshots I see that there is a huge increase in memory when opening the window with the collection view. Instruments pinpoints this memory increase to the `[collectionView setContent:data];` line. This memory is never reclaimed. Any ideas?

EDIT: I access the data object like this:

```
NSArray *data = [[[[MWWeatherController sharedInstance] cachedData] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u",index]] objectForKey:@"daily"];
```

Comment: Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made the ViewController for the CollectionView KVO compliant?

Has the XIB for the CollectionView an ArrayController?

Bind the CollectionView of the XIB to the arrangedObjects of the ArrayController and set the Items through your ViewController method e.g. setMyCustomObjectsArray, that again sets the array that is observed by the ArrayController.

Make sure you release everything correctly in your custom object's dealloc method too.

Comment: also, is instruments pointing out a memory leak, or simple huge amount of memory? And what is 'huge'. When it is a memory leak keep in mind that instruments just points out the location in code where it has found that a memory leak exists, it is not necessarily the location that is responsible for that memory leak.

Comment: How do I know if my collection view item is KVO compliant? It's all managed by IB, no subclasses or anything. I just tried managing the collection view's content with an array controller, but Instruments heapshot analysis still points the memory increase to the line where I add objects to the array. Also, I do release everything properly in my custom object's dealloc method.

Comment: Regarding your original Question: actually you should only set the items of the array and not assign the array itself. The array should be observed by the view controller's arraycontroller.

Comment: OK, after some more investigating, it looks like using an array controller fixed the memory increase! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not releasing data in your scope ... if you own the 'data' object make sure you release it.

Some query to answer it better --

1. How you allocate 'data'?
2. Who is releasing it?
3. [collectionView setContent:data]; more code snippet around this line

Comment: data is stored in an `NSDictionary` in a singleton class. data is not there just for the collection view, i use that data elsewhere in the app. I've updated my question showing how I access data.